# Change UIViewObject name from integer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview

i have alot of UIView objects;

```
//View 2.Satir
UIView *view11;
UIView *view12;
UIView *view13;
UIView *view14;
UIView *view15;
UIView *view16;
UIView *view17;
UIView *view18;
UIView *view19;
UIView *view20;
```

and I want to read from them with a loop, like in this example:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<1; i++) {
    if ([[ratio objectAtIndex:i]intValue] == 100 ) {
        rd = 0;
        gr = 0.5;
        bl =0;

        view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rd  green:gr  blue:bl  alpha:1.0];

        /* i want to do this
        view(i).backgroundColor = ..........  
        i wanna return all views  in for loop */
    }
}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Put all your views in an array, or IBOutletCollection if they are set up in interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the views to a NSMutableArray object :

```
    NSMutableArray *viewArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [viewArray addObject:viewXX];
```

Then iterate by :

```
    int index = 0;
    for (UIView *view in viewArray) {
        if ([[ratio objectAtIndex:index] intValue] == 100 ) {
            rd = 0;
            gr = 0.5;
            bl = 0;

            UIView *tempView = [viewArray objectAtIndex:i];
            tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rd green:gr blue:bl alpha:1.0];
        }

        index++;
    }
```

Comment: Would suggest using the `for(NSView* view in viewArray)` ... syntax instead. It's generally faster as it avoids a couple of message sends each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Put all Views in an Array

Then loop through that array and ask the i-th index of that array. 
You will then get the appropriate UIView that you seek.

Answer (score -1):

Insert all the views in an NSMutableArray
like:

```
NSMutableArray *viewArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[viewArray addObject:myView];

    int index = 0;
    while (index<[viewArray count]) {
    if ([[ratio objectAtIndex:index] intValue] == 100 ) {
        rd = 0;
        gr = 0.5;
        bl =0;

        UIView *tempView = [viewArray objectAtIndex:i];
        tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rd green:gr blue:bl alpha:1.0];
        index++;
}
```